# How to measure the text height when it is drawn on a canvas?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

Is there any method returns the height of any text drawn on the canvas?

Comment: canvas has the method `measuretext`

Comment: @blackbelt actually, i ahve checked that method, but it returns only the width not the height

Comment: you are right, sorry. You can try with Paint.getTextBounds. This method fills up a rectangle (that you have to allocate), representing the bound of the string you provide as parameter. `rect.bottom - rect.top` should be the text's height